# What circuit I need to lower 20MHz 3.3-0V square wave to 0.01-0V square wave for very low load driving?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, ac, converter, electronic-load

My FPGA board outputs the 3.3-0V square wave at 20MHz. I need to convert it to 0.01-0V square wave to drive the very low load (0.1 Ohm). What kind of circuit I need and Is there anything I need to be careful?

Comment: What on earth is this driving? Does it really have 0.1 ohm *impedance* at 20MHz?

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like you have no clue about what you _actually_ want. You'll get better help if you post the schematic and information about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're only talking about 1 mW of power, so my first thought is that a pulse transformer of some sort would be the best approach. However, your application requires a very large turns ratio (330:1) that is not likely to be available commercially. Perhaps you could come up with a circuit that cascades 2 (18.2:1), 3 (6.91:1) or 4 (4.26:1) transformers.

For example, [Pulse Electronics](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Pulse%20PDFs/BX2542,2606.pdf) has a 4.25:1 transformer intended for ADSL applications that would get you very close to what you need (326:1), but you'd need 4 of them.

Comment: This would work with a purely AC signal which is why I discounted it. The op states the signal is a 0 to 3.3V square wave required to be converted to +10mV and 0V. Of course there is a chance an AC output signal will still be good enough for his needs.

Comment: @Andyaka: It's a fair point, and I don't particularly like it either, especially after checking out the available transformers. I think a simple buffer will do the job (see my other answer), but the OP needs to clarify his load requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to source 100 mA (10 mV across 0.1 ohms) so that rules out most op-amps or simple voltage dividers using resistors. I would attenuate the signal using a resistor divider to give the 10 mV peak signal then use an op-amp and BJT configured to drive that sort of current: -

[image]

Vin is the attenuated signal and Rload is the 0.1 ohm load. Things to be careful about: -

- Input offset voltages of the op-amp can introduce a significant error so choose the device with care
- You will probably need a dual supply with some op-amps
- Choose a fast op-amp
- Get LTSpice and simulate it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation but the problem is not the current that pass through the load. It does not require so much current. What I want to know is the circuit that can attenuate the 3.3Vp square wave to 0.1 Vp square wave at 20MHz.

Comment: @Yossiri : you misunderstand the problem you are trying to solve. 0.01V across 0.1 ohm is 0.1A which is a high current, and that's the most important part of the problem. A simple resistive divider (2 resistors) between your 3.3V source and Vin will solve the rest. However at 20MHz this solution is going to be difficult to get right (need a pretty fast opamp for a start!) and I think Dave Tweed's transformer is better. (I'd suggest one transformer : 10:1 if you can find it, requiring 10mA drive, and a 3.3 ohm resistor giving a 34:1 voltage drop into your load.

Comment: @BrianDrummond a transformer isn't going to work with offset voltages as specified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you care whether the square wave gets inverted? The simplest thing to do would be to use a transistor buffer to drive a constant current through a resistor to control the output voltage, something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBUtfW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that Q1 is a high-frequency transistor with a low C<sub>BE</sub> to minimize the Miller coupling. C1 improves the transient response (especially at turn-on) by increasing the AC gain. Run the simulation to see the results. R1 is a standard 1% value that gets you very close to exactly 10 mA through the transistor, and exactly 10 mV across R2.

Note, however, that this circuit will NOT drive 100 mA into a 0.1-Ω load. This is based on your statement that you don't need that — but then your stated requirements are inconsistent. Please clarify.

---

EDIT: Actually, the following variation, which basically scales everything by a factor of ten, performs fairly well at 100 mA. This assumes the load resistance is an accurate 100 mΩ

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdhCKT.png)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to control the current through your load. Why not simply add a series resistor? The problem with very low resistance loads is that even a tiny difference in either the load impedance or the output voltage will cause a large swing in the current going through the load.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

R1 represents the output impedance of the FPGA. If it's much higher than that, buffer it with a CMOS single-gate buffer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fReMqE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]